# Lowest level Windows Phone raw input handling

Tags: xaml, winapi, input, windows-runtime

Is there a way to get a low level input data on Windows Runtime? Which won't be intercepted by DirectManipulation (yes, I've read [Where did all my gestures go?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx) article, but there is no acceptable solution)? I need it on Windows 8.1/Windows phone 8.1 platforms. I didn't find a sample or article about it yet. It would be great if you share code sample with me.